# How to select an option from a select drop-down list with Hound?

Tags: testing, elixir, integration-testing, hound

I have the following drop-down list:

```html
<select id="cities" name="cities">
  <option value="paris">Paris</option>
  <option value="london">London</option>
  <option value="rome">Rome</option>
</select>
```

I am writing integration tests in **Elixir** with [**Hound**](https://github.com/HashNuke/hound) and I'd like to select an element from the list above before submitting my form. Can I do that with Hound?

I couldn't find anything about drop-down lists in the [**Hound documentation**](https://hexdocs.pm/hound/).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Currently there is no Hound function dedicated to selecting an element from a drop-down list.

However, you can use [**`find_element/3`**](https://hexdocs.pm/hound/Hound.Helpers.Page.html#find_element/3) to find the element that corresponds to the option value you want to select, then feed this element to [**`click/1`**](https://hexdocs.pm/hound/Hound.Helpers.Element.html#click/1) to select it:

```rb
find_element(:css, "#cities option[value='london']") |> click()
```

[**More information on this GitHub issue**](https://github.com/HashNuke/hound/issues/72)

---

#### Implementation example

```rb
defmodule CustomHelpers.Hound do
  use Hound.Helpers

  def select_drop_down(drop_down_id, option) do
    find_element(:css, "##{drop_down_id} option[value='#{option}']") |> click()
  end

  def select_drop_down_within(element, drop_down, option) do
    find_within_element(element, :css, "##{drop_down_id} option[value='#{option}']") |> click()
  end
end
```